# Problem from Dixon&Mortimer textbook: (allegedly) sufficient conditions for a transporter between two finite subsets to be non-empty

Tags: group-theory

I should perhaps begin by apologizing for asking a not very profound question, but there is something that bothers me about exercise 1.5.19 from **Permutation groups** by Dixon&Mortimer. May I restate the hypothesis in a language closer to my personal preference. For any action of a group $G$ on a set $A$ and any subset $X\subseteq A$ define its **fixator** as $$\mathrm{Fix}_{G}\ X=\bigcap_{x \in X} \mathrm{Stab}_{G}\ x$$
when $X \neq \emptyset$ and set in particular $\mathrm{Fix}_{G}\ \emptyset=G$.
Assume now the following for a given **transitive** action of $G$ on $A$:

1. $B, C \subseteq A$ are **finite** such that $|B| \leqslant |C|$
2. $\mathrm{Fix}_{G}\ B$ and $\mathrm{Fix}_{G}\ C$ act **transitively**
   on the complementary subsets $A \setminus B$ respectively $A\setminus C$.

Then the exercise would have it that **there exists an operator** $\lambda \in G$ such that $\lambda B \subseteq C$. The exercise also asks whether the alleged result remains valid for infinite subsets $B$ and $C$.

Although I can't come up right away with a counterexample, these hypotheses of mere transitivity seem too weak to afford the nonemptiness of the transporter of $B$ to $C$. Expressing the conditions of the problem in terms of a certain point stabilizer and intersections of some of its conjugates (which is what the fixators would amount to) also doesn't seem too useful. There will exist of course only finitely many injections from $B$ to $C$, however why should one of them act like one of the operators of $G$ on $B$?

I can't completely deny the possibility of there being some trickery of maneuvering $B$ into $C$, but at any rate I can't see how. If anyone could enlighten me, I would be grateful.

Comment: Move as much as you can of $B$ into $C$, and suppose there is still some $b$ in $B$ that you have not managed to move into $C$. Use an element in the fixator of $C$ to move $b$ out of $B$ and then use an element in the fixator of $B$ to move $b$ from its current positiuon outside of $B$ into $C$.

Comment: Thank you kindly for your reply! There is just one detail that needs to be ascertained in order to carry out the argument as you suggested it, namely that $B\cup C \neq A$. I am not entirely sure whether the conditions of the problem would preclude this instance.

Comment: Yes you are right that is a problem - I will think some more.

Comment: Another observation right off the bat is that apart from the ''singular instance'' which requires separate treatment, the hypothesis of finiteness on $C$ was unnecessary. It may play a role in preventing the ''singular'' instance.

Comment: But the result is false when $B$ is allowed to be infinite. You can have silly counterexamples like $C=A$ and $B = A \setminus \{a\}$.

Comment: Entirely agreed, I was only referring to the hypothesis on $C$ being apparently superfluous (the one on $B$ certainly isn't).

Comment: But even when one assumes that the complement of $A$, $B$ have maximal cardinal, one has the counterexample where $G$ is the group of finitely supported permutations.

Comment: @DerekHolt But it's false when $A$ is finite. Indeed, take $A$ partitioned into two subsets $B,C$ with $|B|\le |C|$, and let $G\simeq S_B\times S_C$ be the stabilizer of $B$ (and hence of $C$).

Comment: @YCor: such a choice for $G$ precludes transitivity from the onset. The argument proposed by Derek Holt is quite sound, except for a catch.

Comment: Oh, yes you're right. I know Derek's argument is right but precisely I was trying something where $B\cup C=A$.

Comment: I am still unable to solve this. The problems in that book are typically at most moderately difficult, so I wonder if the authors have made a mistake here, or at least underestimated its difficulty.

Comment: @Derek Holt  Kind sir, your help has been much appreciated, and as you point out the chances are quite high that the authors had an oversight when publishing this exercise. Probably not wise to persevere in trying to explore something that wasn't meant to be too revelatory to begin with.

Comment: It is not as hard as I thought! See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use Dixon&Mortimer's notation $G_{(X)}$ for what you call the fixator of $X$ in $G$. And like D&M, I very much prefer to use right actions, so I will use $B^g$ where you write $gB$.

Choose $g \in G$ such that $|B^g \cap C|$ is as large as possible, and then replace $B$ with $B^g$. If $B \cap C = B$ then we are done so suppose not. So there exists $b \in B \setminus C$. Since $|C| \ge |B|$ and $B,C$ are finite, there exists $c \in C \setminus B$.

If $A \ne B \cap C$, then there exists $a \in A \setminus (B \cap C)$, and we can find $g \in G_{(C)}$ with $b^g = a$ and $h \in G_{(B)}$ with $a^h=c$, so $b^{gh} = c$, and since $(B \cap C)^{gh} = B \cap C$, we now have $(B \cap C) \cup \{c\ \} \in B^{gh} \cap C$, contrary to the maximality of $|B^g \cap C|$.

It remains to deal with the case when $A = B \cup C$, in which canse $A$ is the disjoint union of $B \cap C$, $B \setminus C$ and $C \setminus B$ (so in particular $A$ is finite). By transitivity of $G$ on $A$ (which we haven't used yet), there exsists $g \in G$ with $c^g = b$. Since $c \not\in B$, $g$ can map at most $|B \setminus C| - 1$ elements of $B$ into $B \setminus C = A \setminus C$. So $g$ must map at least $|B| - |B \setminus C| + 1 = |B \cap C| + 1$ elements of $B$ into $C$. Hence $|B^g \cap C| > |B \cap C|$ again contradicting the maximality of $|B \cap C|$.

Comment: Thank you again! Your noble perseverance has shone light on the matter once and for all. As a remark, it seems indeed that the hypothesis that $C$ be finite is indeed superfluous (the only necessary aspect being the cardinal inequality between the two).